# Stored procerudure that calculate number of rows with same number and place that value to other table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I need help with an assignment where I'm supposed to create a Stored Procedure in SQL. I'm new to SQL and it's the first course in databases that I take. I'm using SQL Server Managment Studio 2012.

I have 2 tables, table book, and table bookcopy. Table book has three columns, isbn (the primary key), title and nrOfCopies. The bookcopy table also has three columns, barcode (the primary key), status and isbn( a foreign key that references the isbn-column in table book).

So the assignment is to create a stored procedure for a specific isbn-value (the number of rows with the same isbn-number) that updates the nrOfCopies-column in the book-table. The number of rows for a specific isbn-number will be the value in the nrOfCopies-column for that isbn-number in the book-table.

I tried to do it like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spNrOfBooks
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @calcNr AS INT
    SET @calcNR = (SELECT COUNT(isbn) FROM bookcopy)
    UPDATE book SET nrOfCopies = @calcNr WHERE isbn LIKE (SELECT isbn FROM bookcopy)
END
```

When I execute this procedure I get an error message (Msg 512).

Can someone please help me by pointing out what I can do to solve this?

Comment: I doubt that Msg 512 is  the only text of that error message. Show it complete

Comment: You need to read a course on sql first. There are too many things wrong with your procedure. It has to many problems to begin explaining

Comment: the inner query (SELECT isbn FROM bookcopy) brings all the rows and used in a like expression

Comment: "So the assignment is to create a stored procedure for a specific isbn-value".  That suggests that your stored procedure should take an argument.

Comment: Can you suggest any good tutorials on where i can read about the things you mean? Very thankful for your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correct you need a procedure that counts the number of copies `for a specific isbn number` in table bookcopy, and than updates table book with that count.
If that is the case than it should look something like this.
( I just used varchar(100) for isbn because I dont know how your isbn is defined)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spNrOfBooks (@isbn varchar(100))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE book 
    SET    nrOfCopies = (select count(*) from bookcopy where isbn = @isbn)
    WHERE  isbn = @isbn
END
```

you can use it like this

```
execute spNrOfBooks '12345678901234567'
```

Comment: Thank you very much GuidoG! It worked exactly as i wanted it to :)

Comment: @JulijusErgül If my answer helped you then consider upvoting it and accepting it as answer

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spNrOfBooks
    @isbn VARCHAR(17)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE B
    SET B.nrOfCopies = (
        SELECT COUNT(*) FROM bookcopy bc
        WHERE bc.isbn=B.isbn
    )
    FROM book B
    WHERE @isbn IS NULL OR B.isbn=@isbn
END;
GO
```

The procedure could update all `nrOfCopies` or it could update only the value for a speciffc '@isbn' that is supplied via the parameter.

The `OR` operator in the `WHERE` clause could eventually lead to some performance problems according to my experience. This could be avooided by using two SPs (one with and one without the `@isbn` parameter), or by using an `IF` clause inside the procedure.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This gets you the outcome to need;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spNrOfBooks

AS

UPDATE x 
SET x.nrOfCopies=xx.CopiesCount
from book x
inner join
(
select
    CopiesCount=COUNT(1),
    isbn
from
    bookcopy
group by
    isbn
)xx on x.isbn=xx.isbn
```